# Why swipe down to refresh is not working for my website?

Tags: javascript, css

i am using https://demo.interface.club/limitless/demo/template/html/layout_1/full/index.html

this theme for my admin panel, but some how swipe down to refresh functionality is not wokring.

i want this functionality on mobile devices, but some how it is not working.

i tried different solutions but none of them worked,

here some css properties i tried,

```css
.allow-pull-to-refresh {
    overflow: auto !important;
    overscroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

and i gave this class to body,

but it is not working,

i also tried some script but that also didn't work,

```js
function preventDefaultTouchmove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultTouchmove, { passive: false });

document.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultTouchmove);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS properties you set are good to go

```
.allow-pull-to-refresh {
    overflow: auto !important;
    overscroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

In JavaScript code you are adding an event listener then you are removing it in next line. Better way to manage is making a function and then calling it where it is needed.

```
function preventDefaultTouchmove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultTouchmove, { passive: false });

function enableDefaultTouchmove() {
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefaultTouchmove);
    }
```

For swipe to refresh you would need to handle it differently by calculating the move on y-axis and setting some preset threshold. Here is an example how you can handle it.

```
var moveY;
var dist;
var threshold = 100; // Adjust this value as needed

//tackles the first touch on the screen, and saves it in array.

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    moveY= touchobj.clientY; // Get the starting vertical position
    dist = 0; // Reset distance moved.
}, false);

//checks the distance moved from initial position

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    dist = touchobj.clientY - moveY; // Calculate distance moved vertically
}, false);

//checks with the threshold value we have set and refreshes the page if condition is met

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    // If distance moved is greater than the threshold, trigger refresh
    if (dist > threshold) {
        // Call your refresh function here
console.log('Page Refresh')        
location.reload();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: the code which you provided is not working, most likely i want to do it by some css properties, adding js for that is not valid solution. btw thanks